# In ui:input select how to set default value to "all"

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I would like to set default value as "all" after loading the page. how to set"all"in case of page load

```
<aura:attribute name="options" type="List" default="all"/>
   <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
     <div class="slds-col">
         <span>
             <div class="slds-form-element">
                 <ui:inputSelect aura:id="Aircraft Manufacturer"   label="Aircraft Manufacturer" change="{!c.FindAllChanges}">

                  <aura:iteration items="{!v.options}" var="item">                          
                        <ui:inputSelectOption text="{!item.label}" value="{!item.value}"  label="{!Document}"  />
                    </aura:iteration>

                </ui:inputSelect>    

            </div>
        </span>
    </div>
```

---

```
({
doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.Displayaircraftmanufacturer(component, 
  'Aircraft_Manufacturer__c', 'Aircraft Manufacturer');
 }
```

---

```
   ({
     Displayaircraftmanufacturer : function(component, fieldName,elementId )  {
    var action = component.get("c.getselectOptions");
    action.setParams({
        "objObject": component.get("v.objInfo"),
        "fld": fieldName
    });
    var opts = [];
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        if (response.getState() == "SUCCESS") {

            var allValues = response.getReturnValue();

            if (allValues != undefined && allValues.length > 0) {
                opts.push({

                    label: "All",
                    value: ""
                });
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < allValues.length; i++) {
                opts.push({

                    label: allValues[i],
                    value: allValues[i]
                });
            }

           // component.find(elementId).set("v.options[0]", opts);
           component.set("v.options",opts)

        }

    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"value" should be set to "true" when selected, and "false" when not.

```
        if (allValues != undefined && allValues.length > 0) {
            // default selected
            opts.push({ label: "All", value: true });
            // All others not selected
            allValues.forEach(label => opts.push({ label: label, value: false });
        }
```